# Defining a function using transfinite recursion.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, transfinite-recursion

For $p,q\in \mathbb{Q} :p<q $ we define $(p,q) :=\{ x\in \mathbb Q : p<x<q  \}$
and we want to define an order like this $$(p,q) < (t,l) \iff p<q$$
and I want to prove that there is an order perserving function from $\langle \mathbb{Q} ,<_{\mathbb Q} \rangle$ to $S = \{ (p,q): p,q\in \mathbb Q , p<q \}$ with the order we defined.

I understood that I have to define a family of functions that the union on them is the function that I want. But I'm having some troubles with the induction assumption, what conditions I have to assume to find such a function. I'll be really glad to hear how you knew that these are the right assumptions.

thank you very much

Comment: Strange that your order definition only depends on one element (the left one).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes i know but still its on purpose. it is a partial order

Comment: Why do you need transfinite recursion here? (1) $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so in principle you could do it with just a standard recursion; (2) why do you need recursion anyway when $q\mapsto (q,q+1)$ is an embedding?